# Xenial 16.04 xrandr doesn't list HDMI after kernel upgrade

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, hdmi, intel, xrandr

I have been using Xenial for a couple of weeks. After kernel upgrade (4.4.0-34) and grub upgrade yesterday my third monitor ceased to function.

I realised HDMI port is not listed with Xrandr.

I spent many debugging but couldn't find a solution below are some findings.

I tried solutions like trying nvidia drivers disabling Nvidia to Intel. Reinstalling intel and nvidia and ubuntu desktop on non graphic mode. Switched back to 4.4.0-31 kernel before doing all the solutions. And ran out of bullets :(

---

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD95 Analog [92HD95 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

`xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

---

`lshw -c video`:

```
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by following suggestions on other posts. What worked for me I used boot-repair logging from Live CD and repaired Grub. That might be the case because I upgraded from 14.04 and might have done some subtle things during the upgrade?. I had to reboot twice to see the changes effectively, dunno why???

Now I can happily work back again with 3 monitor setup. Although there are still messages annoying me in syslog!